# Click event doesn't fire on an audio element in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, audio, click, addeventlistener

I have an audio element in my DOM.
I executed the following command and it seems like the click event does not fire for some reason:

```
$0.addEventListener('click',function(){console.log('click')});
```

When i tried adding a mouseover handler it worked as expected:

```
$0.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){console.log('mouseover')});
```

In Firefox the click event works properly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> "If the user agent exposes a user interface to the user by displaying controls over the media element, then the user agent should suppress any user interaction events while the user agent is interacting with this interface. (For example, if the user clicks on a video's playback control, mousedown events and so forth would not simultaneously be fired at elements on the page.)"
> — from [The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#user-interface)

It's intended not to work, so "malicious" websites can't capture users' clicks on media controls. So it's not advisable to get around it in general cases; but if you really have to, you have to follow some hack like programmatically wrapping the audio element in a transparent element with a higher z-index (be careful with z-indices and transparency) and capturing the clicks for the said element.

Comment: Hope this is a similar way of achieving this requirement.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/9gw8e5-jo8yah?file=index.html,index.js

Answer (score 0):

Directly, it wont work.

You will need to add a shimified div aroudn it to get the click event.

Javascript:

```
function onAudioElClick() {
    console.log('click');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div onclick="onAudioElClick()" style="position:absolute; z-index:9999; width:300px; height:30px;"></div>
<audio></audio>`
```

Comment: i actually don't want to change the html. are you saying this is a bug in chrome?

Comment: this is a desired behaviour.

Comment: why? its not documented that audio elements do not trigger click events, and in firefox it works...

Comment: It no longer works in firefox, but is still not documented that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange that `mouseover` works but `click` not.

If you will wrap `audio` element inside to other element like `div` then you can handle `click` event:

JavaScript:

```
<div>
    audio element
    <audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" autoplay></audio>
</div>
```

HTML:

```
var el = document.querySelector("div");
el.addEventListener('click',function(){console.log('click')});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b3sbmqpj/

Comment: Remove the text nobody asked for, add the controls attribute and your click event will not be triggered..