How to know when <audio> is clicked
In my React code I have this audio:
<audio
  ref={audioRef}
  className={'d-flex flex-grow-1'}
  style={{ height: '30px', width: 'calc(100% - 50px)' }}
  src={source}
  controls={true}
  autoPlay={false}
>

When the user clicks on one of the controls, or in a space where there are no controls, I need to be notified.  I tried adding an onClick property but it is never called:
<audio
  ref={audioRef}
  className={'d-flex flex-grow-1'}
  style={{ height: '30px', width: 'calc(100% - 50px)' }}
  src={source}
  controls={true}
  autoPlay={false}
  onClick={() => console.log('clicked!!!')}  // clicks do NOT trigger this onClick
>

How can I know when the audio tag or any of its controls are clicked?

hmm audio doesnt have an onclick according to mdn, however it has onPlay, onPause event

audio tag or any of its controls, do you mean the empty space around the controls too

apparently it has its reasons https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149785/13583510 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257757/onclick-event-on-audio-element

@mr.loop yes, the empty space, too
